hiding entire cell in excel using vba on the entireColumn property not quite working
Hiding entire column in excel
The following code is not executing the ".EntireColumn.Hidden = true" for some reason...it loops through and when the string is matched it will go to this line Cells(iRow, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True  but it will not hide the columns and I don't know why?  It does not give an error...it just keeps looping until done, but none of the columns get hidden
Public Function Hide_Columns_on_Cell_Text_Value(SearchStr As String) As String
    StartColumn = 2
    LastColumn = 97
    iRow = 2
    
    For i = StartColumn To LastColumn
        needle = SearchStr
        haystack = Cells(iRow, i).Value
        
        If InStr(1, haystack, needle, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
         Cells(iRow, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(iRow, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    'MsgBox (SearchStr & " columns hidden")
    
End Function

Any ideas?

A Function returns a value to a cell. To modify the worksheet, use a macro (Sub)

Exactly how are you calling this function?

Thanks for the replies...Ron, I tried using the "Sub", but after saving the module and then opening the "Macros" on the sheet, there is nothing in the list.  So I tried using the "Function" just to get it to do something.

Tim, I'm calling this function by putting this formula into cell A1 --> =Hide_Columns_on_cell_text_value("Variance")

When you call a VBA function from a worksheet as a UDF, there are limitations on what it can do- see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.

Thanks I think I found out the issue...a SUB won't display inthe "Macros" list if it has an argument passed in...that is why it wasn't showing up...all works now. thanks for the replies.

I found the resolution to my issue here:
Macros Not Showing Up in Macro Table
I initially tried using a "Sub Procedure", but when it didn't show in the macro list I tried using a "Function", which was executed, but did not change the layout of the sheet.  Ron's comment above helped me to understand that changing the layout of the cells worked in Sub procedures, but not functions.  after removing the argument in my Sub Procedure it showed in the macro list and now hides the columns. thanks
